# Keep state of other divs when expanding current div

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Currently, I have this small example where if I click on the image icon, it shows the answer to the question and when I click the image again, it hides the answer.

So, given this scenario where I click on the image icon for the first question, it shows the answer. Then if I go the next div and click on the image icon, it should show me the answer for the second div and keep the state of the first div. That is, it should not close the first div.

Currently, in my example, it closes the first div when the second one is open. How can I keep the state of the other divs on the page when the current div is expanded?

Here's the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/SzkrltPYPmt4WRijVFuD?p=preview

main code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let part of parts">
      <h1 class="question">{{part.question}}
      <img (click)="myclick(part.id)" style="float:right;" [src]="getimage(part.id)"
     class="ic_add"/></h1>
      <p *ngIf="showanswer == part.id" class="answer" > {{part.answer}}</p>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
 public showAnswer = false; 

    parts = [];
    shoanswer = 0;

     imgsrc="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rounded-functions-1/154/arrow-circle-direction-down-512.png";

    constructor(){
      this.parts = [
          {
            id: 1,  
            question: "Foo?",
            answer: "Bar"
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            question: "ABC?",
            answer: "123"
          }
      ]
    }

    myclick(id) {
      this.showanswer = this.showanswer == id ? 0 : id;
    }

    getimage(id) {
      return this.showanswer == id ? "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/rounded-functions-1/154/arrow-circle-direction-down-512.png" : "images/ic-add.png";
    }

}
```

Comment: You may want to check out this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/oVoPIA0ZbMMauth812Ls?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the showing/not showing state in the respective **part** variable in the template.

```html
<div *ngFor="let part of parts">
  <h1 class="question">{{part.question}}
      <img (click)="part.showanswer = !part.showanswer" style="float:right;" [src]="getimage(part.id)"
     class="ic_add"/></h1>
  <p *ngIf="part.showanswer" class="answer">{{part.answer}}</p>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

I made a copy plunk with the behaviour [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/PvyeGN8cfqOS8jsuL4vy?p=preview).

For the image you can use the new property to determine which image you should add.

You can pass the **part** variable instead of just it's id to the **getimage** method.

```html
<img (click)="part.showanswer = !part.showanswer" style="float:right;" [src]="getimage(part)"
     class="ic_add"/>
```

And in the **getimage** method you can use the **.showanswer** property (or other properties if you have any) to determine which image you should show.

```js
    getimage(part) {
      console.log(part.id + " " + part.showanswer);
      let image = part.showanswer ? "https://images.pexels.com/photos/79290/black-and-white-code-programming-tech-79290.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"
      : "https://images.pexels.com/photos/256369/pexels-photo-256369.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb";

      return image;

    }
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/iFvpvh1tGZw0lVRP6Hbw?p=preview)'s the updated plunker as well.

Comment: Ok, so this works nicely but the state of the image does not change! I have two images. One is shown when the view loads, then a new image is supposed to be set when the user clicks on it and the answer is shown. If the user clicks on it again, the old image appears again. The behavior above breaks that flow.

Comment: thats very handy or also can contain an array for all questions. Please update the parts new structure so that it could be understandable to every one.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
myclick(id) {
      this.showanswer = this.showanswer == id ? 0 : id;
    }
```

You have only one showanswer for all divs,
you need a flag/boolean for every div